# hasOwnProperty with more than one property

Tags: javascript, object, methods, hasownproperty

I'm trying to discover if an object has some properties and I'm having trouble using the hasOwnProperty method.

I'm using the method on an array (I know the documentation states a string).

The following line returns true:

```
{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }.hasOwnProperty( ["a"]);
```

This line returns also true:

```
{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }.hasOwnProperty( "a", "b");
```

But this one returns false:

```
{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }.hasOwnProperty( ["a", "b"])
```

And I need it to return true. I'm using Object.keys(object) to get the properties that I'm using, and it returns me an array, so I need to use an array on hasOWnProperty.

Is there some theoric concept I'm missing? And is there some way to fix this problems?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are two things going on here.

First, `hasOwnProperty` only takes one argument. So it'll ignore whatever other arguments you pass to it.

Second, (and I'm simplifying slightly here) it's going to convert that first argument to a **String**, and *then* check to see if the object has that property.

So let's look at your test cases:

The reason `{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }.hasOwnProperty( "a", "b");` returns `true` is because it's **ignoring the second argument**. So really it's just checking for "a".

`{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }.hasOwnProperty( ["a", "b"])` returns `false` because the first argument, `["a", "b"]`, gets converted to `"a,b"`, and there's no `{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }["a,b"]`.

To find out if a given object has **all** the properties in an array, you can loop over the array and check each property, like so:

```
function hasAllProperties(obj, props) {
    for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(props[i]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Or, if you're feeling fancy, you can use the `every` function to do this implicitly:

```
var props = ["a", "b"];
var obj = { "a": 1, "b": 2 };
var hasAll = props.every(prop => obj.hasOwnProperty(prop));
```

I hope that helps clarify things. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check the object's own properties, you could use the `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` method. It *returns an array of all properties (including non-enumerable properties except for those which use Symbol) found directly upon a given object.*

```js
let o = { "a": 1, "b": 2 };
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o).forEach(k => console.log(`key: ${k}, value: ${o[k]}`));
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the documentation, it seems that the `hasOwnProperty()` method takes either a string or a symbol as an argument. So I think `hasOwnProperty()` isn't capable of taking a collection of strings and testing if the object has each one as a property.

I think another approach would be to take the array of strings and iterate through each one. Then for each string in your array (the properties you want to test for), you could test if the object has that property. Here's an example:

```js
const o = new Object();
var propsToTest = ['a', 'b'];
o.a = 42;
o.b = 40;

var hasProperties = true;
propsToTest.forEach(function(element) { // For each "property" in propsToTest, verify that o hasOwnProperty
  if(!o.hasOwnProperty(element))
    hasProperties = false;
});

console.log(hasProperties);
```

Answer (score 2):

So this is an old question and I'm kinda surprised no one else has thought to write it but this is usually solved using `.every` on the array. So for the original question, the code should be something like:

```
["a", "b"].every((item) => ({ "a": 1, "b": 2 }.hasOwnProperty(item)))
```

This will return a simple true.
Array `.every` will run a condition for every item in an array and only return true if the condition is true for all item.
See [the the mozilla web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Comment: Writing it in a more reusable format would be more helpful, as in create a small arrow function or standard function to take in the parameters. Also the way this is written, you are actually testing the properties on a new object every time that function the `every` function is invoked and while it works, it is misleading and ideally you want to test the set of properties of a single object.

Answer (score 1):

First, in terms of getting your third snippet to return true, I don't think that's possible. The best you could do would be to check each property individually:

```js
const obj = { "a": 1, "b": 2 };
console.log(["a", "b"].every(p => obj.hasOwnProperty(p)))
```

Which should give you what you want.

---

**But to understand why the first two returned true, but the third false:**

The `hasOwnProperty` method only accepts a single argument (additional arguments are ignored), and it expects that argument to be a string. If the argument is not a string, then JavaScript will attempt to coerce it to one (usually by using a `.toString` method).

So your first two snippets are equivalent because:

`["a"].toString() === "a"`, so `hasOwnProperty(["a"])` is the same as `hasOwnProperty("a")` after the argument is converted to a string.

Then in your second snippet, the second argument `"b"` is simply ignored, leaving it equivalent to just `hasOwnProperty("a")` again.

And finally, your third snippet uses `["a", "b"]`, and `["a", "b"].toString() === "a,b"`, which is not a property of your object.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a `for...in` loop like this

```
const obj = { "a": 1, "b": 2 };

for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
           console.log('has', key, obj[key]);
        } else {
           console.log('not', key, obj[key]);
        }
}
```